# How effective is Opera Mini's encryption? Can it hide activity on a WiFi network?

Tags: encryption, web-browser

I'm curious since I discovered the nature of how browsing works in Opera Mini. A URL request is sent to Opera's servers, they download the page then compress it to lower bandwidth. They use a file format that is only used by Opera Mini. I like to visit websites like reddit's WTF and I don't think my university network admins would appreciate seeing that in the history.

Comment: May be dupe of [How private is the Opera Turbo feature of Opera?](http://superuser.com/questions/293924/how-private-is-the-opera-turbo-feature-of-opera)

Comment: @user10008 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172309/228369 Duplicate isn't the right word here, since it is on a different site. Still a useful link to share though.

Comment: Couple of considerations here.  First, Opera turbo is not meant for privacy, or security.  You should not be using it as such, and instead be using something that is designed for it, like Tor.  Secondly, the important thing is the University's policy on access to the network, you don't want to be breaching it in order to gain privacy, as they'll just ban you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the service you are talking about is Opera Turbo, which the web browser, Opera Mini, makes use of.

I would imagine that network admins at a school do not care the least about what gross/weird sites you look at in your free time as long as you are not using a ton of bandwidth or breaking the law. I know that isn't your question, but it is still relevant. I'd read your university's terms of use and then not really worry about what you are looking at as long as you don't violate it.

Also, this is important to understand as there is a lot of old information out there:

> If you browse a secure site, like your bank or email, Opera Turbo stays out of the way. Your sensitive data is sent directly between your device and the secure site.

[source](http://www.opera.com/turbo)

That means that Opera Turbo does not break [end-to-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle) integrity. (That's a good thing!)

---

### Quick test:

When I visit reddit.com/r/netsec, this is what Fiddler (a packet capturing tool) sees:

```
GET http://sitecheck2.opera.com/?host=www.reddit.com&hdn=1T%2Bc%2BVh6YJohgWpVDp9S7Q%3D%3D
200 OK (text/xml)

CONNECT http://af.opera.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

CONNECT http://autoupdate.geo.opera.com:443
200 Connection Established ()
```

First, it makes a request to `sitecheck2.opera.com` which reveals the host... and possibly the entire URL you want to visit. I think this is some kind of anti-phishing thing from Opera. In my opinion, this undermines a lot of the anonymity you are expecting to have with this solution. Then the connection to af.opera is established, and you don't see any new traffic.

I am not going to attempt to do some kind of security audit. I don't have the knowledge/skills/time to do so. The basic answer is that you don't use Opera Mini for this, you use Tor or some other SSL tunneling service. Again, this could be a clear violation of your university's Terms of Use. Even Opera Turbo could be a violation if they ban all proxy servers.

Comment: This answer isn't strictly correct. Opera Mini and Opera Turbo are two different compression services that are used by various Opera products. Opera for Android can use either Opera Mini ("extreme" compression) or Opera Turbo ("high" compression). In both cases the connection to Opera's servers is encrypted.